# STL heaps parameterized by comparator

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, stl, heap

I would like to write a wrapper class around STL heaps that allows the user to provide their own comparator. I would like to have the comparators be functors so that they may close over some state.

For example, consider maintaining a sorted list of 2D points. The sorting criterion is distance from a given point. I'd like to provide a default comparator that sorts based on distance from the origin, but also give the user the option to compare based on distance from an arbitrary point.

My problem is: I don't know how to properly structure the functor inheritance to make this work in a flexible manner. Here is the sorted points example to illustrate what I want:

```cpp
struct Point {
  int x, y;
  Point(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
  static float dist(const Point &a, const Point &b) {
    const int dx = a.x - b.x, dy = a.y - b.y;
    return sqrtf(dx*dx + dy*dy);
  }
};

// Abstract Point comparison base class.
class Comparator {
public:
  virtual bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) = 0;
};

// Sorts Points according to distance from the origin.
class DefaultComparator : public Comparator {
public:
  virtual bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    const Point zero(0,0);
    const float dl = Point::dist(zero, lhs), dr = Point::dist(zero, rhs);
    return dl < dr;
  }
};

// Sorts Points according to distance from a given Point.
class RelativeComparator : public Comparator {
public:
  RelativeComparator(Point p) : _point(p) {}
  virtual bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    const float dl = Point::dist(_point, lhs), dr = Point::dist(_point, rhs);
    return dl < dr;
  }
private:
  const Point _point;
};

class SortedPoints {
public:
  SortedPoints(Comparator &comp) : _comp(comp) {}

  void push(Point p) {
    _points.push_back(p);
    std::push_heap(_points.begin(), _points.end(), _comp);
  }

  bool pop(Point &p) {
    if (_points.empty()) {
      return false;
    } else {
      std::pop_heap(_points.begin(), _points.end(), _comp);
      p = _points.back();
      _points.pop_back();
      return true;
    }
  }

private:
  typedef std::vector<Point> PointList;
  Comparator &_comp;
  PointList _points;
};

int main() {
  DefaultComparator defaultComp;
  RelativeComparator relativeComp(Point(100,100));
  SortedPoints list1 = SortedPoints(defaultComp);
  SortedPoints list2 = SortedPoints(relativeComp);
  Point p(0,0);
  list1.push(Point(15,15));
  list1.push(Point(13,13));
  list1.push(Point(5,5));
  printf("List one (relative to 0,0):\n");
  while (list1.pop(p)) {
    printf("%d,%d\n", p.x, p.y);
  }

  list2.push(Point(15,15));
  list2.push(Point(13,13));
  list2.push(Point(5,5));
  printf("List two (relative to 100,100):\n");
  while (list2.pop(p)) {
    printf("%d,%d\n", p.x, p.y);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Due to the way the inheritance is structured, I'm getting a compilation error when the STL heap implementation tries to instantiate a Comparator (because it's an abstract class). The precise error is:

```
sortedpoints.cpp: In member function ‘void SortedPoints::push(Point)’:
sortedpoints.cpp:51: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Comparator’
sortedpoints.cpp:17: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Comparator’:
sortedpoints.cpp:19: note:  virtual bool Comparator::operator()(const Point&, const Point&)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_heap.h: In function ‘void std::push_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, std::vector<Point, std::allocator<Point> > >, _Compare = Comparator]’:
sortedpoints.cpp:51:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_heap.h:203: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Comparator’
sortedpoints.cpp:17: note:   since type ‘Comparator’ has pure virtual functions
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_heap.h: In function ‘void std::__adjust_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _Distance, _Distance, _Tp) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, std::vector<Point, std::allocator<Point> > >, _Distance = long int, _Tp = Point]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_heap.h:238:   instantiated from ‘void std::__pop_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Tp) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, std::vector<Point, std::allocator<Point> > >, _Tp = Point]’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_heap.h:265:   instantiated from ‘void std::pop_heap(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, std::vector<Point, std::allocator<Point> > >]’
sortedpoints.cpp:58:   instantiated from here
```

What is the proper way to accomplish this sort of task? If my Comparator inheritance strategy is a bad one, I'd like to know that too: this is just the first method I tried.

Comment: If you see e.g. [this `std::push_heap` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap), you will see that the comparator is passed *by value*, meaning the compiler want to create an instance of your `Comparator` class.

Comment: Too bad you're not using C++11. You could just replace the `_comp` in your heap function calls with `std::ref(_comp)` if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do what I want using regular OOP paradigms. Using the C++11 functional features suggested by @pzed is a good idea, however the rest of my codebase is not C++11 and I'd like to stick with consistent paradigms.

The strategy is to have the base Comparator class close over a subclass instance, and simply pass through the comparison to the subclass.

For example, the three classes from above become:

```cpp
class Comparator {
public:
  Comparator(Comparator &c) : _comparator(c) {}
  virtual bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    return _comparator(lhs, rhs);
  }
private:
  Comparator& _comparator;
};

// Sorts Points according to distance from the origin.
class DefaultComparator : public Comparator {
public:
  DefaultComparator() : Comparator(*this) {}
  virtual bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    const Point zero(0,0);
    const float dl = Point::dist(zero, lhs), dr = Point::dist(zero, rhs);
    return dl < dr;
  }
};

// Sorts Points according to distance from a given Point.
class RelativeComparator : public Comparator {
public:
  RelativeComparator(Point p) : Comparator(*this), _point(p) {}
  virtual bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    const float dl = Point::dist(_point, lhs), dr = Point::dist(_point, rhs);
    return dl < dr;
  }
private:
  const Point _point;
};
```

And the rest of the code stays the same, for example we can now do:

```
RelativeComparator relativeComp(Point(100,100));
SortedPoints list1 = SortedPoints(relativeComp);
```

as before, and it works.

Hopefully this isn't considered an abuse of inheritance.

Comment: That's definitely abuse. :-)  This might work even if you remove the keyword virtual.  So with this solution, when it copies the Comparator you preserve the original comparator and dispatch to that.

Comment: I was just typing up an answer suggesting something like this. :) Since you know the function signature of the comparator, you can write a small wrapper (ala std::reference_wrapper) that forwards calls to a stored reference. Check it out [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/843324398fca8ed1). All that's needed is to replace `_comp` with `wrap(_comp)` where you call the heap functions.

Comment: Check out @MobyDisk's answer. Using templates (not inheritance) for the comparator is the idiomatic way to handle this in C++.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation for [push_heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/push_heap/?kw=push_heap%20push_heap), you'll see that it takes the comparator by value, so it's going to try to copy your `Comparator` object.

`template <class RandomAccessIterator, class Compare>
  void push_heap (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                   Compare comp);`

Instead of holding a reference to the `Comparator` object in `SortedPoints`, you could create a `std::function` object that matched the `Comparator` function signature and pass that into push_heap (or boost::function if you're stuck on C++03).

For your code, you could try something like this:

```
class SortedPoints
{
public:
  typedef std::function<bool (const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)> MyComparator;  // <-- Add this typedef
  SortedPoints(MyComparator comp) : _comp(comp) {}  // <-- Use MyComparator instead of Comparator&

  void push(Point p) {
    _points.push_back(p);
    std::push_heap(_points.begin(), _points.end(), _comp);
  }

  bool pop(Point &p) {
    if (_points.empty()) {
      return false;
    } else {
      std::pop_heap(_points.begin(), _points.end());
      p = _points.front();
      _points.pop_back();
      return true;
    }
  }

private:
  typedef std::vector<Point> PointList;
  MyComparator _comp;  // <-- Use MyComparator instead of Comparator&
  PointList _points;
};
```

Comment: Question: I tried the original code and your solution on Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and it fails to compile unless I add a less than operator to the Point class.  When I run the app, it calls the lessthan operator during the pop.  Why is this?  "bool operator <(const Point &b) const "

Comment: @MobyDisk: There's a bug (apart from the bug I was asking about) in that code: `pop_heap()` should take `_comp` as a third parameter. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Substitute boost::function for std::function if you can't use C++11.  The usage semantics between the two are essentially identical.

Comment: @pzed: I'd rather not pull in such a large dependency as boost for such a small piece of the project :(.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by making 3 changes:

1. Removed the polymorphism in favor of templates
2. Added the comparator to the pop_heap call as well.
3. Added const to the operator ()

I get this:

```
// Sorts Points according to distance from the origin.
class DefaultComparator {
public:
    virtual bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) const {
        const Point zero(0, 0);
        const float dl = Point::dist(zero, lhs), dr = Point::dist(zero, rhs);
        return dl < dr;
    }
};

// Sorts Points according to distance from a given Point.
class RelativeComparator {
public:
    RelativeComparator(Point p) : _point(p) {}
    virtual bool operator()(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) const {
        const float dl = Point::dist(_point, lhs), dr = Point::dist(_point, rhs);
        return dl < dr;
    }
private:
    const Point _point;
};

template <class C>
class SortedPoints
{
public:
    SortedPoints(C &comp) : _comp(comp) {}

    void push(Point p) {
        _points.push_back(p);
        std::push_heap(_points.begin(), _points.end(), _comp);
    }

    bool pop(Point &p) {
        if (_points.empty()) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            std::pop_heap(_points.begin(), _points.end(), _comp);
            p = _points.front();
            _points.pop_back();
            return true;
        }
    }

private:
    typedef std::vector<Point> PointList;
    C &_comp;
    PointList _points;
};

int main()
{
    DefaultComparator defaultComp;
    RelativeComparator relativeComp(Point(100, 100));
    SortedPoints<DefaultComparator> list1 = SortedPoints<DefaultComparator>(defaultComp);
    Point p(0, 0);
    list1.push(Point(15, 15));
    list1.push(Point(13, 13));
    list1.push(Point(5, 5));
    printf("List one (relative to 0,0):\n");
    while (list1.pop(p)) {
        printf("%d,%d\n", p.x, p.y);
    }

    SortedPoints<RelativeComparator> list2 = SortedPoints<RelativeComparator>(relativeComp);
    list2.push(Point(15, 15));
    list2.push(Point(13, 13));
    list2.push(Point(5, 5));
    printf("List two (relative to 100,100):\n");
    while (list2.pop(p)) {
        printf("%d,%d\n", p.x, p.y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```